# Full-weighted restriction of elements of large array to a smaller array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a Matlab array that has Ns elements in it. For each element in that array, I'd like to compute a weighted average of that element and its neighbours (averaging a total of n values) on either side. The elements come from periodic data so the array can be thought of as circular.

I'd then like to store the weighted average in place of that element and downsample the array to an Nd = Ns/n long array.

Ideally, I'd like to use something similar to full weighted restriction- I'd weight the element more than I'd weight its neighbours in the average. For example, for n=3, I'd weight the element with 0.5 and its neighbours each with 0.25.

Is there a simple and efficient way to do this in Matlab without having to use the downsample function? My code has to be compatible with an older version of Matlab on a remote server.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I did it with a loop and wrote logic to do the weighted average. Since my data is periodic, I used repmat on my array to make sure it got end conditions correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average), which can be obtained with a [FIR filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response). Assuming that `x` is your array and it's one-dimensional, you can use the [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) command for that:

```
y = filter(ones(1, n), 1, x);
```

To downsample the result, use indexing:

```
y_downsampled = y(1:n:Ns);
```

In simple words, the `ones(1, n)` denote the weights. If you want to have one element have weigh more than the others, modify it to your liking. In your example, you would change it to `[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]`.

If your array is two-dimensional, you should use another suitable filtering command such as [`filter2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html).

Comment: I believe there should be a division by n in the first argument to filter to get an average there.